# texture mapping in 3d surface matlab?

Tags: matlab, graphics, data-visualization, matlab-figure, mesh

I am trying to add texture to a 3D surface I have in std format:

```
fv = stlread ( 'tree_house.stl' ); % read 3D volum mesh into MATLAB, extract the vertices and elements of the mesh.

patch(fv,'FaceColor', [0.8 0.8 1.0], ...
         'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
         'FaceLighting', 'gouraud', ...
         'AmbientStrength', 0.15);
```

I calculated the vertices:

```
v = fv.vertices; % vertices [x y z] columns
f=fv.faces;
nx = 120;  % the size of the grid
ny = 120;  % the size of the grid

% create a grid in x and y
x = linspace(min(v(:,1)),max(v(:,1)),nx);
y = linspace(min(v(:,2)),max(v(:,2)),ny);
```

And this is how I try to add texture:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = gridtrimesh(f,v,x,y);
surf(x,y,Z,'facecolor','texturemap', ...
           'cdata',I,'edgecolor','none');
```

but the result is not what I want. More specifically, the color of texture changes and the 3D surface is not mapped. How can I solve that?